# Uploading to DropBOX using API which accepts Only UTF

Tags: pdf, itext, dropbox

Please help me ,I am creating a pdf in memorystream and I want to pass this stream as utf string to dropbox API upload Put call,i am using spring.social to communicate with dropbox.

```
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
            iTextSharp.text.Image img = text.Image.GetInstance(CurrRecipt.imgurl);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();
            document.Add(img);
            document.Close();
```

when I convert the stream to string using Encoding.GetString or Utf8.convert the Pdfis not readable. 
i can not pass this as byte[] array as my spring rest framework can not convert this to Http request body.

Same behaviour is observed when i read the Pdf from the disk into stream and convert this stream to string and write to new pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes` methods are for converting .Net's implementation of strings into raw byte arrays in a specific format. PDFs are binary files so using a string convertor doesn't make sense.

When Dropbox says this:

> Every string passed to and from the Dropbox API needs to be UTF-8 encoded

They're talking about the commands themselves that you send, not the data. As long as you stick to the basic lower 128 ASCII characters (English letters, numerals, punctuation, etc) then you usually don't even have to worry about this as those map one-to-one with Unicode and are represented the same way using UTF-8.